# Remove irrelevant files with post-receive hook

Tags: git, sh, githooks

I’m using a bare Git repo and automate deployment via hooks. I’ve set up a git remote locally that I can push to and the server updates the files automatically.

However, I’m using [Kirby CMS](https://getkirby.com/) which is a file-based CMS, meaning any unnecessary files should be removed. Basically, the folder in which my hook does `git checkout` should be identical to the state of the repo.

Here’s my hook script:

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/html/myrepo --git-dir=/var/repo/myrepo checkout -f
cd /var/www/html/myrepo/assets
npm install --production
```

I’ve read about `git clean`, but as far as I understand, it can be used on repos with a work tree, which my bare repo doesn’t have.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

First, after running `git-checkout` in the hook script you *do* have a working tree, it is just in a separate directory from the bare repo.

Second, the script you have *will* remove files *that are under the control of git*, when they are removed from the repo (e.g., with `git rm`).

That said, if you want to also remove any locally created files from your working tree, you can do that by adding `git clean` to the same hook script, after the checkout:

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/html/myrepo --git-dir=/var/repo/myrepo clean -fd
```

where `-f` means force and `-d` means also remove directories (but do read [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) before doing this in any real environment). To test it you can give the `-n` (dry run) option which will not remove anything but just print what it would remove, i.e.:

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/html/myrepo --git-dir=/var/repo/myrepo clean -nd
```

**Edit:** as commented by @jthill, `git-clean` has further options (`-e`, `-x`, `-X`) for selectively removing untracked files based on combinations of a given pattern and `.gitignore` (see [the manual](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean) for details).

Comment: I might do `git ... clean -dfx`, in case there's a `.gitignore` in the checkout and some matching junk in the deployment tree.